In ANTD tree drag and drop, how to prevent drop as child if it is a leaf
In ANTD tree if I drag and drop a node below any leaf node then I have two options. Either drop the element as a sibling or drop it as a child or drop as a sibling. To drop as sibling we have to just drop it below any node however if we want to drop as child then move the drop marker a little right and then drop.
I want to disable this feature of dropping as a child.
Dropping as sibling:
enter image description here
Dropping as child:
enter image description here
I tried to search for any prop that might help but not able to find one. I only found the solution to handle this in onDropHandler however this will not stop the tree from dropping as child.

Check https://ant.design/components/tree#treenode-props docs. As you can see there's a isLeaf property. You can customize your drag&drop action with that!
